# Need help to get the value of the object from the json file and save it to the save json in azure data factory

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory, etl, transformation

I have a json input file which looks like the below in the Azure Blob storage. I need only the array as the output and save it as the json file using the azure data factory

```
{
  "output": [
    {
      "name": "xyz",
      "address": "xyz"
    }
  ]
}
```

i need the below output

```
[
  {
    "name": "xyz",
    "address": "xyz"
  }
]
```

I have tried the below things

1. i tried copy activity and chosen array of object as the file pattern.
2. i used lookup activity and read the json and used variable to get only the array but can't save the output to the json file using copy activity
3. Tried some of the possibility available in the data flows

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Advanced editor** in copy activity mapping to achieve your requirement.

This is input JSON as same as yours.

[image]

Give the above JSON dataset to both copy activity source and sink and give **Array of objects** as file pattern in the sink.

Follow the below steps for the copy activity mapping.

[image]

**Result file after Pipeline execution:**

[image]